# Android - Filter LiveData List based on Selected Item change in ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I have a AndroidViewModel for one of my fragments which contains a LiveData List, and I have another property for selected item of another LiveData List. Below is an example of what I am talking about:

```
class TeamViewModel(app: Application): AndroidViewMode(app) {
    ...

    val selectedTeam = MutableLiveData<Team>()

    val allTeams: LiveData<List<Team>>
        get() = repository.getAllTeams().toLiveData()

    val allPlayers: LiveData<List<Player>>
        get() = repository.getAllPlayers().toLiveData()

    ...
}
```

***Note:** `getAllTeams` and `getAllPlayers` returns a RxJava Flowable List, which I then convert to LiveData List via `.toLiveData`*

Currently, `allPlayers` represents all the players from all teams. I'd like to make it so that whenever the value of `selectedTeam` changes, that `allPlayers` gets filtered down to only display players from the `selectedTeam`.

What I've tried is to filter `allPlayers` directly like so:

```
val allPlayers: LiveData<List<Player>>
    get() = repository.getAllPlayers()
                .flatMap { list -> Flowable.fromIterable(list)
                    .filter {
                        player -> player.team == selectedTeam.value?.team
                    }
                }
                .toList()
                .toFlowable()
                .toLiveData()
```

But as you may or may not guess, it doesn't update the filter for `allPlayers` whenever `selectedTeam` changes.

Is there anyway to dynamically change the filter for `allPlayers` whenever `selectedTeam` changes?

**EDIT**

Thanks to @EpicPandaForce, the final solution I came up with is as followed:

I created this extension method:

```
fun <T, R> LiveData<T>.switchMap(func: (T) -> LiveData<R>) = Transformations.switchMap(this, func)
```

to make the code more readable.

I've also created a function in my repository called `getAllPlayersFromTeam(team: Team)` which, as the function specifies, gets all the players from a team.

Finally this is the end result of my property:

```
val allPlayersFromSelectedTeam: LiveData<List<Player>>
    get() = selectedTeam.switchMap { 
        repository
            .getAllPlayersFromTeam(it)
            .toLiveData()
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to `switchMap` over the `selectedTeam`, and possibly renamed "allPlayers" because that's a lie. :P

```
val selectedTeam = MutableLiveData<Team>()

val allTeams: LiveData<List<Team>>
    get() = repository.getAllTeams().toLiveData()

val playersOfSelectedTeam: LiveData<List<Player>>
    get() = Transformations.switchMap(selectedTeam) { team ->
         val allPlayers = repository.getAllPlayers().toLiveData()
         val players = when {
             team == null -> allPlayers
             else -> {
                 Transformations.switchMap(allPlayers) { playerList ->
                     val filteredPlayers = MutableLiveData<List<Player>>()
                     val filteredList = playerList.filter { player -> player.team == team }
                     filteredPlayers.value = filteredList
                     filteredPlayers
                 }
             }
         }
         players 
    }
```

Which I really hope it works as I wrote it here directly.

Comment: The solution works, thanks. Are you able to if you can explain in more detail on why you need to use two switchMaps for it to work?

Comment: Technically I only need the second switchMap because your repository doesn't seem to be able to provide a `repository.getAllPlayersForTeam(team)` LiveData. If it did, I wouldn't filter the LiveData and map it over to a new LiveData (with the filtered data set), because I could get that LiveData directly.

Comment: I'll look further into adding a function into the repository to do just that, thanks.

Comment: One thing to note is that as you are using Kotlin, you might want to consider something like, `fun <T, R> LiveData<T>.switchMap(func: (T) -> LiveData<R>) = Transformations.switchMap(this, func)` just for better chaining.

Comment: Good idea, I've made the necessary changes (including the extension method), and is really clean now. Thanks for your time :)